# Woocommerce related products section shows the same products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I would like to display the related products section on my product pages, but it shows the actual product in all columns. 
Here is my code:

```
<?php
    while ($loop->have_posts()): $loop->the_post();
        $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($product->get_id()), 'single-post-thumbnail'); ?>
        <div class="col-lg-3 related-tour">
            <article>
                <div class="featured-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo (!empty($featured_image)) ? $featured_image[0] : '';?>);"></div>
                <div class="article-info">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="<?php echo $product->get_permalink();?>"><?php echo $product->get_name();?></a>
                    </h2>
                    <p class="category">
                        <span><?php pll_e( 'Categories:' ); ?></span>
                        <?php echo $product->get_categories(', ', ' ' . __(' ', '  ', $cat_count, 'woocommerce') . ' ', ' ');?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

What should I change to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

DON'T use a custom function for showing a related product.

So function `woocommerce_output_related_products` show related product.

View inside this file `/single-product/related.php`. (https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/single-product/related.php)

You can change product arguments for the related products query which using `woocommerce_output_related_products_args` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_output_related_products_args', 'my_woocommerce_output_related_products_args' );
function woocommerce_output_related_products_args( $args ) {
    $args['post__not_in'] = [ get_the_ID() ];

    return $args;
}
```